# Testnet: mandatory-script-verify-flag-failed when doing OP_RETURN

Tags: bitcoind, testnet, op-return

For some reason I keep getting `error: {"code":-25,"message":"Missing inputs"}`

EDIT: Updating error now that the full testnet blockchain is downloaded

```
"code":-26,"message":"16: mandatory-script-verify-flag-failed (Operation not valid with the current stack size)
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error. Can someone help me debug or point me in the right direction ?  Using TESTNET3

```
0100000002f739b61642740a6f9b24859a30cf5f248722e9dd8f38f981e5d8a7c1f16354350100000000ffffffff0a31a52da8f2fc706d15025810eca7b6bfa53bdabcc5feefc5d55e1d2f728a170000000000ffffffff0290333200000000001976a9141ce00dca082ca1215c9e5a7a3237d267124fea3288ac00000000000000001a6a1857485920546573746e65742067697665206d65207061696e00000000



{
"Version": "1",
"LockTime": "0",
"Vin": [
    {
        "TxId": "355463f1c1a7d8e581f9388fdde92287245fcf309a85249b6f0a744216b639f7",
        "Vout": "1",
        "ScriptSig": {
            "Asm": "",
            "Hex": ""
        },
        "CoinBase": null,
        "Sequence": "4294967295"
    },
    {
        "TxId": "178a722f1d5ed5c5effec5bcda3ba5bfb6a7ec105802156d70fcf2a82da5310a",
        "Vout": "0",
        "ScriptSig": {
            "Asm": "",
            "Hex": ""
        },
        "CoinBase": null,
        "Sequence": "4294967295"
    }
],
"Vout": [
    {
        "Value": 0.0329,
        "N": 0,
        "ScriptPubKey": {
            "Asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 1ce00dca082ca1215c9e5a7a3237d267124fea32 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
            "Hex": "76a9141ce00dca082ca1215c9e5a7a3237d267124fea3288ac",
            "ReqSigs": 1,
            "Type": "pubkeyhash",
            "Addresses": [
                "mi9dcxfvGTsDCs46UZXXYQ8JH5MLcGxMxz"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "Value": 0,
        "N": 1,
        "ScriptPubKey": {
            "Asm": "OP_RETURN 57485920546573746e65742067697665206d65207061696e",
            "Hex": "6a1857485920546573746e65742067697665206d65207061696e",
            "ReqSigs": 0,
            "Type": "nulldata",
            "Addresses": null
        }
    }
],
"TxId": "998221ecf0e85c1b3f1e06fbdfd5bb6b2957c244fcdbb8a2e2a8ad9b3270d440"
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. Just noticed that the inputs were messed up . Correct decoded transaction below:

```
{
  "txid": "5a15e2e0980ec2523d7a564cfd990dc9e435beeb4550f79723c65e753d368c13",
  "version": 1,
  "locktime": 0,
  "vin": [
    {
      "txid": "355463f1c1a7d8e581f9388fdde92287245fcf309a85249b6f0a744216b639f7",
      "vout": 1,
      "scriptSig": {
        "asm": "3045022100db6505e9445c0030efdb7e2852771de8d6a7513c02487bfa3b2fae832e18d726022013395a3984e9d959c624fd5ad4d639e1820a0923090924d906415b3fbb54b9e901 0327b1cfc3981b27bccfc17937fc1b8b14091effee6fd9f2d1de8f0b6d46e90ec5",
        "hex": "483045022100db6505e9445c0030efdb7e2852771de8d6a7513c02487bfa3b2fae832e18d726022013395a3984e9d959c624fd5ad4d639e1820a0923090924d906415b3fbb54b9e901210327b1cfc3981b27bccfc17937fc1b8b14091effee6fd9f2d1de8f0b6d46e90ec5"
      },
      "sequence": 4294967295
    },
    {
      "txid": "178a722f1d5ed5c5effec5bcda3ba5bfb6a7ec105802156d70fcf2a82da5310a",
      "vout": 0,
      "scriptSig": {
        "asm": "3045022100d60838e19e6d18f4c964cba303afbe9975c693b25ccafe1abc8887246046c26b02205032c7863ac76a0030332e0128a3ff41f4d9061e4d02e0374c6254af4b92307001 0327b1cfc3981b27bccfc17937fc1b8b14091effee6fd9f2d1de8f0b6d46e90ec5",
        "hex": "483045022100d60838e19e6d18f4c964cba303afbe9975c693b25ccafe1abc8887246046c26b02205032c7863ac76a0030332e0128a3ff41f4d9061e4d02e0374c6254af4b92307001210327b1cfc3981b27bccfc17937fc1b8b14091effee6fd9f2d1de8f0b6d46e90ec5"
      },
      "sequence": 4294967295
    }
  ],
  "vout": [
    {
      "value": 0.0329,
      "n": 0,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 1ce00dca082ca1215c9e5a7a3237d267124fea32 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
        "hex": "76a9141ce00dca082ca1215c9e5a7a3237d267124fea3288ac",
        "reqSigs": 1,
        "type": "pubkeyhash",
        "addresses": [
          "mi9dcxfvGTsDCs46UZXXYQ8JH5MLcGxMxz"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "value": 0,
      "n": 1,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "OP_RETURN 57485920546573746e65742067697665206d65207061696e2e204661696c696e6720626c6f636b6578706c6f72657273",
        "hex": "6a3057485920546573746e65742067697665206d65207061696e2e204661696c696e6720626c6f636b6578706c6f72657273",
        "type": "nulldata"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Yep, there you go. Transaction was unsigned since inputs had no scriptsig